# IE11 - CustomEvent Polyfill stop triggering events after PDF download

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, polyfills

As [CustomeEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) is not supported in IE11, so added [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent#Polyfill) from MDN.

That is working fine in other browsers (Chrome, Firefox) and even IE11 but it stops triggering/listening event after very specific steps. That is download a PDF and trigger "change" event.

Steps to reproduce the bug:

1. Open [Demo](http://result.dabblet.com/gist/d0b55b335d49d199dc0391b6f2130224/ffe4c254b4888ed2063d0b488e2e7b4e5060220a) in IE11/Win7
2. Download PDF
3. Change Checkbox, it will call native change event but CustomEvent does not trigger.

Open DevTool's console to visualize console.logs.

Kindly suggest alternative polyfill/solution/suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not solve the original problem that `CustomEvents` are no longer triggered after downloading the PDF, but I have noticed if you put `target="_blank"` on the `<a>` href link, the events continue to work after the download.

Comment: Security Tip: Opens External Anchors Using rel="noopener"
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/noopener